# ¿Cómo definir una lista de incógnitas?

Tags: python, lista

estoy intentando definir una matriz donde cada elemento tiene multiplicando una incógnita, para ello quiero definir una lista de la siguiente forma:
listay=[y_1,y_2,y_3,...,y_{N-1},y_N]
Sin embargo, no sé cómo hacerlo. Hice esto, pero me retorna error:

```
from sympy import Symbol 
lista=[]
for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
   ["y_" + str(i)]=Symbol('y_'+str(i)) 
   lista.append("y_" + str(i))
```

Me retorna el siguiente error: cannot assign to operator

Si elimino el Symbol el problema es que me retorna strings, y yo necesito incógnitas para luego poder asignárselo a los valores de la matriz :(

```
lista=[]
for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
  lista.append("y_" + str(i))
```

Este me retorna la siguiente lista: ['y_1', 'y_2', 'y_3', 'y_4', 'y_5']

¿Qué puedo hacer? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta sería la siguiente:

```
from sympy import Symbol 

lista=[]

for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
    # creamos el simbolo y lo añadimos a la lista
    lista.append(Symbol("y_" + str(i)))

print(lista)
```